# Finding layer with maximum value for each pixel in terra

Tags: r, terra

I have a raster like this here: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1AEKu4TKpzJg95oXv8dxep24xpXaesr0F

The tif has 11 Layers (timestamps). For each pixel I want to find the timestamp with the maximum value. For some reason one approach works with that data, one does not.

```
r = rast("au.tif")
terra::app(r, which.max) # works
terra::app(r, function(x){which.max(x)}) # does not work
```

For the second approach I get this error which I am not really sure about:

```
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].
```

If I am using another raster, both work. So I was wondering why that might be:

```
b = rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
terra::app(b, which.max) # works
terra::app(b, function(x){which.max(x)}) # works also
```

Becua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because there are pixels that are all NA.

```
b = rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
terra::app(b, function(x){which.max(x)}
```

works but...

```
b[[1]][1,1] = NA
b[[2]][1,1] = NA
b[[3]][1,1] = NA
terra::app(b, function(x){which.max(x)})
```

fails:

```
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].
```

I think this is because R will be calling `which.max` on a vector of NAs and returning a length-0 vector, which messes up how `app` puts things together.

Also, you can just do `which.max(b)` since there's a method for `terra` rasters.

Comment: Ah yes I thanks a lot! I tested the `which.max` function on a vector that contains NAs and it didnt fail. But makes sense of course:)